# Shiny display values in r enviroment or global r

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I would like thath my shiny ap used the Data.Frames inside the user global enviroment as radio buttons, if that is impossible a text or table would also work, here are failed attempts at it.

```
k<<- Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())

ui = fluidPage(    
textOutput("k")

output$k <- ("This is where a don't know what to code, "k" doesn't work)
```

Comment: Also the k<<- filter doesnt work when lauched as an app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use your `Filter` statement as choices for a `selectInput`, and then use `get` to fetch the dataframe from the global environment.

```
A=data.frame(x=1:10)
B=data.frame(x=1:5)
C=data.frame(x=1:3)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('df_picker','Pick dataframe',Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())),
  tableOutput('df')
)

server <- function(input,output, server)
{
  output$df <- renderTable({
    get(input$df_picker)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! It also gives me the opportuny to give interactivity with the user, for plots and more, thanks for going beyond what I had asked, I had settled with an non-interactivity Shiny App that served as a kind of user form now I can manipulate the users datasets outside of R.